# Expect script variable matching ruined by a space

Tags: expect

I'm trying to automate some operations with the VC systems I administer, and the manufacturer has MANY inconsistencies in their interface.

I'm trying to match a system H323 name and device name, but...

If I do **systemname get**, the answer is **name\r\n**
If I do **h323name get**, the answer from the device is **name \r\n**. -> the space between name and CR is killing me.

In both cases, I'm using
**expect "*\r\n"** and then using **$expect_out(0,buffer)** as my variable.

Of course, later on when I try to match the names, I always get a negative, even though the names are the same.

How can I manipulate the variables or change what I'm expecting to get:
1. rid of the space bar for h323name
or
2. add a space bar after systemname so my query will work?

Comment: AFAIK expect is Tcl, and looking at [this page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/string.htm#M45) I think `[string trim $expect_out(0,buffer)]` might do what you want. It gives the trimmed string as return value.

Comment: Great suggestion! Worked with variations:
(argh having problems to format it)

**set systemtrim [string trimright $systemname "\r\n"]
set h323trim [string trimright $h323name " \r\n"]

if {[string equal -nocase $systemtrim $h323trim] == 1} {
 send_user "True"
 }
if {[string equal -nocase $systemtrim $h323trim] == 0} {
 send_user "False"
 }'**